# how to create sqlite database with three column in android programming?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my android program I want to create sq-lite database in which three column should be there that so for each first column there should be max four entry's in third column so how should I create it ? and again I want use method like insert, update, get all, delete , and again there should be one which can take first column as reference and operate entry's from third column . so can any please suggest how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

To create SQLite db in android you must create a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper then override onCreate and onUpgrade method in onCreate you can create tables like :

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private SQLiteDatabase mWritableDB;
private SQLiteDatabase mReadableDB;


private static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "user";
private static final String USER_COL_ID = "id";
private static final String USER_COL_NAME = "userName";
private static final String USER_COL_AGE = "age";

private static final String QUERY_USER_CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " (" + USER_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                USER_COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + USER_COL_AGE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 );";

public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
    mReadableDB = getReadableDatabase();
    mWritableDB = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    Log.e("query", QUERY_USER_CREATE_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(QUERY_USER_CREATE_TABLE);
```

}

on constructor pass context of activity ,DBName,cursorfactory(null),DBVersion and get instance of getReadable and writable Database so that you can perform insert update and search query using these instance like below:

```
 //to insert a user Value in localDB
public long addUser(User user) {
    long newId = 0;
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(USER_COL_ID, user.getId());
    contentValues.put(USER_COL_NAME, user.getUserName());
    contentValues.put(USER_COL_AGE, user.getAge());
    if (mWritableDB != null) {
        try {
            newId = mWritableDB.insert(USER_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return newId;
}
```

Serach query like

```
// To search user in LocalDB
public User serach(Integer id) {
    User user = new User();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        if (mReadableDB == null) {
            mReadableDB = getReadableDatabase();
        }
        cursor = mReadableDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + USER_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + USER_COL_ID + "=" + id, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        user.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_COL_ID)));
        user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_COL_NAME)));
        int table_age = cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_COL_AGE);
        if (table_age == -1) {
            user.setAge(-99);
        } else {
            user.setAge(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(USER_COL_AGE)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```